# Making the horizontal axis labels clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have a question regarding Google Charts (Column Charts) in specific.
"How do I make the "date" clickable so I can open up a modal dialog (jQuery) with an external page?"

[image: Example]
I have added an example to illustrate what I mean, this is obviously done in Photoshop.
I am able to bring up a alert dialog when I click any of the bars, but that's not really what I am looking for.

I have tried to search for it, but was unable to find something.
Attached is the code I used for making the bars clickable, maybe someone knows how to modify that without having to Google for it.

```
var handler = function(e) {
    var sel = chart.getSelection();
    sel = sel[0];
    if (sel && sel['row'] && sel['column']) {
      var message = "Hi..";
      alert(message);
    }
}
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', handler);
```

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.
 - Robert.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use a `'click'` handler instead of a `'select'` handler, you can more easily interact with other parts of the chart.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6LJhv/6/

Your event object, `e`, will have a `targetID` property.

This `targetID` is not well documented, but if you run the debugger, you can get a sense of what IDs look like.

On the various axis charts (Line, Column, etc.) the `targetID` of the axis labels look something like this: `hAxis#0#label#1`. To break that down, it means that you clicked on the second label of the first horizontal axis (0 based index).

Given that, we can dissect the `targetID` to figure out which label you clicked on from the data if it's discrete.

(If your data is continuous, there isn't necessarily a 1:1 relationship with the labels and rows of data)

```
var handler = function(e) {
    var parts = e.targetID.split('#');
    if (parts.indexOf('label') >= 0) {
        var idx = parts[parts.indexOf('label') + 1];
        alert(data.getValue(0, parseInt(idx)));
    }
};
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', handler);
```

Comment: In my code, first column comes up good, second column it says `18` 3rd column it says `3` 4th `7` and 5th `Uncaught Error: Invalid column index 5. Should be an integer in the range [0-3].` am I missing something?

Comment: I figured it out, it was referring to the wrong place, I had to do this: `if (parts.indexOf('label') >= 2) {` instead of `if (parts.indexOf('label') >= 0) {` Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: can you please tell me where can i add the style for change appearance of the clickable items in the X axis?