# How to make react-google Chart label clickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-charts

I am working on react google-chart [react-google-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-charts) and it is working fine.
What I want to do is to add click event to the labels of horizontal axis and get the label name and do what ever I want to do

I have google a lot but haven't found a correct solution

What I have done is this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";
export default class manpowerGraph extends Component {
    render() {
     const data=[
        ['Year', 'Sales'],
        ['jan', 20],
        ['feb', 100],
        ['march', 55],
        ['april', 120],
        ['may', 200],
        ['june', 220],


      ]
     const options={
        // Material design options
        chart: {
          title: 'Manpower',
        },
      }
        return (
            <div className="manpowerChart">
<Chart
  chartType="Bar"
  width="100%"
  height="400px"
  data={data}
  options={options}
  legendToggle
  chartEvents={[
    {
      eventName: "ready",
      callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
        const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "onmouseover", e => {
          const { row, column } = e;
          console.warn("MOUSE OVER ", { row, column });
        });
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "onmouseout", e => {
          const { row, column } = e;
          console.warn("MOUSE OUT ", { row, column });
        });
      }
    }
  ]}
/>

            </div>
        )
}
}
```

Working code [Working code I want when user click on month label it should fire any event or console](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-charts-scatter-chart-with-onmouseover-and-onmouseout--events-pifkp)

I have found this with `Javascript` [with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598008/making-the-horizontal-axis-labels-clickable)

Answer (score 4):

Change the chart type to `ColumnChart` and then add the `click` handler from `ready` handler.

```
        <Chart
          chartType="ColumnChart"
          width="80%"
          height="400px"
          data={data}
          options={options}
          legendToggle
          chartEvents={[
            {
              eventName: "ready",
              callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
                const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
                var handler = function(e) {
                  console.log(e);
                  var parts = e.targetID.split("#");
                  if (parts.indexOf("label") >= 0) {
                    let idx = parts[parts.indexOf("label") + 1];
                    idx = parseInt(idx);
                    alert(data[idx + 1][0]);
                  }
                };
                google.visualization.events.addListener(
                  chartWrapper.getChart(),
                  "click",
                  handler
                );
              }
            }
          ]}
        />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-charts-columnchart-with-click-handler-cqe1l

## Edit

To answer additional questions:

You can do limited styling of x-axis labels by setting `hAxis.textStyle` in `options`, supported styling options can be found here https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#TextStyle . However, you can not set `cursor` using `textStyle`.

You can not style `svg` through external css. But you can add `style` tag inside `svg` tag. Again, not all css styles work, but fortunately, `cursor` does work.

One crude way of adding `style` inside `svg` is to grab the `svg` element using `document.querySelector` and then add `style` as child. This can be done from your `ready` handler as `svg` element has been created by the time `ready` event is fired.

Updated code now looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Chart from "react-google-charts";
const data = [
  ["Year", "Sales"],
  ["2004", 1000],
  ["2005", 1170],
  ["2006", 660],
  ["2008", 1030],
  ["2009", 1000],
  ["2010", 1170],
  ["2011", 660],
  ["2012", 1030]
];
const options = {
  title: "Company Performance",
  curveType: "function",
  legend: { position: "bottom" },
  enableInteractivity: true,
  hAxis: { textStyle: { color: "blue", underline: true } }
};
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Chart
          chartType="ColumnChart"
          width="80%"
          height="400px"
          data={data}
          options={options}
          legendToggle
          chartEvents={[
            {
              eventName: "ready",
              callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
                let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
                let styles = 'text[text-anchor="middle"] { cursor: pointer; }';
                var css = document.createElement("style");
                if (css.styleSheet) {
                  css.styleSheet.cssText = styles;
                } else {
                  css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));
                }
                svg.appendChild(css);

                const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
                var handler = function(e) {
                  console.log(e);
                  var parts = e.targetID.split("#");
                  if (parts.indexOf("label") >= 0) {
                    let idx = parts[parts.indexOf("label") + 1];
                    idx = parseInt(idx);
                    alert(data[idx + 1][0]);
                  }
                };
                google.visualization.events.addListener(
                  chartWrapper.getChart(),
                  "click",
                  handler
                );
              }
            }
          ]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-charts-columnchart-with-click-handler-k6fv2

Comment: Hey thats cool, but how ca I add style to those labels so to make it look like link, How can I add External style?

Comment: Add  ` hAxis: {textStyle: {color:"blue", "underline":true}}` to options. See updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-charts-columnchart-with-click-handler-298hn

Comment: Is there any documentation for styling like you are doing for underline I have to add several style like cursor:'pointer' and many more, could you help me with any documentations

Comment: After a lot of search I could finally locate the documentation: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#TextStyle However, this does not have option like cursor that you are looking for.

Comment: So how can I change cursor please help me out once

Comment: hey sir could you please help me here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61039619/react-google-chart-not-taking-up-the-options   I am stuck here for so long now please check one whenever you are free

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what is available at the moment for clickable tool tips in react-google-charts is limited.

However in order to configure clickable tooltips for react requires you to set the tooltip option like this:

`tooltip: { isHtml: true, trigger: "selection" }`

*(so that it stays shown when you click)*, **and** you have setup a `select` chartEvent event as follows:

```
  chartEvents={[
        {
          eventName: "select",
          callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
            var selection = chartWrapper.getChart().setAction({
              id: "alertAction",
              text: "Click Me!",
              action: function() {
                alert("Stay away Corona Virus!!");
              }
            });
            console.warn(selection);
          }
        }
      ]}
```

[See my codesandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/sandbox-google-pie-chart-tooltip-lp2vn)

[And here's some google documentation on setAction() function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#setaction), just the way I coded it in my example.  Addtionally, there are the `getAction()` and `removeAction()` functions that tie into chart tooltips found on that same documentation page.

Hopefully this helps you some.

Comment: Hey I have found this kind of example which is working on click of graph columns, what I want is to add click event on the labels i.e jan,feb etc and in your code 2011,2012 which are years I want to add click event on labels. the above code is not gona help me

Answer (score 0):

For making the labels clickable, In the chartEvents which is passed as props under Charts

```
 <Chart 
  chartEvents = {**chartEvents**}
  rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '3' }}  
/>
```

Use can pass this as chartEvents

```
    const chartEvents = [
  {
    eventName: "select",
    callback({ chartWrapper }) {
      console.log("Selected ", chartWrapper.getChart().Ufa.Ei);
    }
  }
];
```

This will return the label name for for the chart on which u have clicked

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-fog-99jpj?file=/src/Treemap/Treemap.js)