# React-google-chart not taking up the options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-charts

I am using `react-google-chart` for displaying my data in graphical form (Bar Chart), As per requirement I have to make a `dual-y-axis chart`

I have already made that chart but the issue is that chart is not taking up the `options`. It is an `Bar` chart when I am putting chart as `ColumnChart` then it is taking options but not rendering as `dual-y-axis-chart` and if I am putting `Bar` as chart type the it is not taking options

What I am missing? Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Chart from "react-google-charts";
const data = [
  ["Month", "CTC", "Gross Salary", "Variation of CTC", "Total No of Employes"],
  ["Jan", 35000, 27000, 10000, 3],
  ["feb", 30000, 24000, 8000, 4],
  ["Mar", 50000, 37000, 7000, 5],
  ["May", 20000, 17000, 5000, 6],
  ["June", 20000, 17000, 5000, 5],
  ["July", 20000, 17000, 5000, 10],
  ["August", 20000, 17000, 5000, 7],
  ["Sep", 20000, 17000, 5000, 5],
  ["Nov", 20000, 17000, 5000, 5],
  ["Dec", 20000, 17000, 5000, 9]
];
const options = {
  width: 900,
  title: "Nearby galaxies",
  curveType: "function",
  series: {
    3: {
      axis: "test"
    }
  },
  legend: { position: "bottom" }
};
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Chart
          chartType="Bar"
          width="100%"
          height="400px"
          data={data}
          options={options}
          legendToggle
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-charts-columnchart-with-click-handler-pspro)

### Edit

It is not even taking `chartEvent` anyhow I want to achieve this things, if not react-google-chart then any other library I am open to any open source chart library.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: @halfer I have written my whole code what I have tried, One thing is not working which I clearly mentioned

Comment: I am not sure how many times I need to remove your begging and pleading and tales of woe and suffering, but I would urge you to have mercy on volunteer editors here if you can. Technical writing is encouraged on this platform: it is much easier to read, and features no distracting emotional coercion. Begging is also counterproductive for you, too; [read this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391945/472495) to understand why.

Comment: @halfer okay fine I will not do that again . Just stuck with this chart library that's why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`options` for `ColumnChart` are different.

See `classicOptions` in the example https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#dual-y-charts

So it works when you replace the options as

```
const options = {
  width: 900,
  title: "Nearby galaxies",
  curveType: "function",
  seriesType: "bars",
  series: {
    3: { targetAxisIndex: 1 }
  },
  vAxes: {
    0: { title: "primary" },
    1: { title: "secondary" }
  },
  legend: { position: "bottom" }
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-charts-columnchart-with-click-handler-y6mo6

Comment: hey just one issue it is not taking `language: 'hi_IN',` in options

Comment: What is the purpose of setting `language`? My understanding is that it is mainly useful for date locale specific formatting, but there are no date fields in your data. `Month` col is treated as 'string'.

Comment: To set language use `chartLanguage` property on `Chart` component.

Comment: I am using `chartLanguage:{language:'en-IN'},` in my option not working.. also I am trying `chartLanguage:'en-IN'`, insided option not working and at last inside chart component I am doing  `chartLanguage={'en-IN'}` it is also not working

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? What is the expected output?

Comment: It is not taking up the language option, please check your  code sandboc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211289/discussion-between-ckedar-and-manish-thakur).

Answer (score 1):

The importing thing here is their comment specifically about `Bar` chart:

> Note here we use Bar instead of BarChart to load the material design version

<sup>https://react-google-charts.com/bar-chart#right-y-axis</sup>

Therefor, the options are a bit different. Instead of passing `title` to the root object, it should be under `chart`.

```js
options={{
  // Material chart options
  chart: {
    title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
    subtitle: 'Based on most recent and previous census data',
  },
}
```

However, seems like it not respects all of the options (`legend` for example).

About `width`, you set `width` prop to `100%` and in options to `900px`. To set the `width, use`width` prop.

Example:

```js
const data = [
  ["Month", "CTC", "Gross Salary", "Variation of CTC", "Total No of Employes"],
  ["Jan", 35000, 27000, 10000, 3],
  ["feb", 30000, 24000, 8000, 4],
  ["Mar", 50000, 37000, 7000, 5],
  ["May", 20000, 17000, 5000, 6],
  ["June", 20000, 17000, 5000, 5],
  ["July", 20000, 17000, 5000, 10],
  ["August", 20000, 17000, 5000, 7],
  ["Sep", 20000, 17000, 5000, 5],
  ["Nov", 20000, 17000, 5000, 5],
  ["Dec", 20000, 17000, 5000, 9]
];
const options = {
  chart: {
    title: "Nearby galaxies",
    legend: { position: "bottom" }
  },
  curveType: "function",
  series: {
    3: {
      axis: "test"
    }
  }
};
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Chart
          chartType="Bar"
          width={900}
          height="400px"
          data={data}
          options={options}
          legendToggle
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-charts-columnchart-with-click-handler-4dywj

---

You can use `ColumnChart` instead. Using this chart you'll be able to customize the legend position and more

```js
const options = {
  title: "Nearby galaxies",
  legend: { position: "bottom" },
  curveType: "function",
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-charts-columnchart-with-click-handler-wltpt

I'm not sure about the `series` prop. I didn't see it in the docs.

Comment: hey it is not taking up option, I want to put language and align  the legends to bottom but still it is coming on right side and it is not taking up language also

Comment: > However, seems like it not respects all of the options (legend for example).

Comment: I know if i use `ColumnChart ` then I can use options but  if I use this it will not give me dual-y axis chart please check your updated answer

Comment: Right. I don't know about other solutions. Sorry.